# Alias with input for git add not working - file not found

Tags: git, alias, git-bash

I have a simple alias for `git add`:

```
[alias]
    test = "!f() { git add \"$1\";}; f"
```

And when I use it, even though the file is in the directory that I have the git bash console open in, I get this:

```
fatal: pathspec 'test_file.txt' did not match any files
```

If I run the command normally without an alias, the file is found.

The config file is in the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration with `git config -l` to ensure you configuration is correct.

One common mistake when setting aliases in Git is including `git` unnecessarily in the last argument. Here is the correct syntax:

`git config --global alias.<desired-alias> "the long version of the command that you want the alias to run, without git at the beginning, and with the desired flags"`

For example, if I wanted an alias for `git log --oneline -5`, I'd set:

`git config --global alias.lol "log --oneline -5"`